# Will interfere the same object for caching in different partials?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Will these two interfere if m is the same instance but it is used in different partials?

```
#in _detailed.html.erb
<% cache m do %>
 ... Detailed view...
<% end %>
```

and then

```
#in _row.html.erb
<% cache m do %>
 ... row in the list...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because `cache_key` is the same.
You can use `<% cache [m, "list"] do %>` and `<% cache [m, "detailed"] do %>`

Comment: How is the cache key calculated for that array?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache.html#method-c-expand_cache_key If the `key` argument provided is an array, or responds to `to_a`, then each of elements in the array will be turned into parameters/keys and concatenated into a single key.

Comment: Thanks:
        def retrieve_cache_key(key)
          case
          when key.respond_to?(:cache_key) then key.cache_key
          when key.is_a?(Array)            then key.map { |element| retrieve_cache_key(element) }.to_param
          when key.respond_to?(:to_a)      then retrieve_cache_key(key.to_a)
          else                                  key.to_param
          end.to_s
        end